# Is this projection linear? $\mathbb{R}[X]\to\mathbb{R}[X], f\mapsto f' $

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that this projection is linear: $\mathbb{R}[X]\to\mathbb{R}[X], f\mapsto f' $
I know that, for a projection to be linear it needs to satisfy the following:
$ \forall \lambda , y \in \mathbb{R} ,\; \forall u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n : A(\lambda u + yv)=\lambda (A(u))+y(A(v))$
This is not very difficult to show with numerical examples such as:
$\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2, (x,y)\mapsto (^{3x\ +\ 2y}_{4x\ +\ \;y})$
However I am pretty clueless on how to answer this  $f\mapsto f' $ question. I would appreciate it if somebody could tell me how to solve this.

Comment: This is not a projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{R}[X]$ the polynomial ring over the reals. For each polynomial $f(x) = a_n X^n + \ldots + a_1 X + a_0 \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ the formal derivative is defined as

$$f'(x) = na_n X^{n - 1} + \ldots + a_1 \in \mathbb{R}[X].$$

Now we show that the map $\mathbb{R}[X] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}[X], \ f \longmapsto f'$ is linear, i. e. $(\lambda f)' = \lambda f'$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ and $(f + g)' = f' + g'$ for all $f, g \in \mathbb{R}[X]$.

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ defined as above. It follows

\begin{align}
(\lambda f)' &= (\lambda ( a_n X^n + \ldots + a_1 X + a_0))' \\ 
&= (\lambda a_n X^n + \ldots + \lambda a_1 X + \lambda a_0)' \\
&= (n\lambda a_n X^{n - 1} + \ldots + \lambda a_1) \\
&= \lambda ( na_n X^{n - 1} + \ldots + a_1) \\
&= \lambda f'.
\end{align}

Now let $g(x) = b_mX^m + \ldots + b_1 X + b_0 \in \mathbb{R}[X]$. Without loss of generality, let $n \geq m$ (otherwise interchange the roles of $m$ and $n$). So we have $b_k = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $m + 1 \leq k \leq n$. I. e. , we can write $g(x) = b_n X^n + \ldots + b_1 X + b_0$. It follows

\begin{align}
(f + g)' &= \left ( \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k X^k  + \sum_{k = 0}^n  b_k X^k \right)' \\
&= \left ( \sum_{k = 0}^n (a_k + b_k) X^k \right)' \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^n k(a_k + b_k) X^{k - 1} \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^n ka_k X^{k - 1} + \sum_{k = 1}^n kb_k X^{k - 1} \\
&= f' + g',
\end{align} 
so the linearity is proven.

Comment: Looks great, only one small typo: $( \lambda f)' = \lambda f'$ instead of $( \lambda f' )= \lambda f'$

Comment: Why can't you start out with your defintion of g(x) as $g(x) = b_n X^n + \ldots + b_1 X + b_0$ instead of starting with the $b_m$ and going through that bit of trouble of changing the indices?

Comment: @user639631 Thanks, I edited the answer. I have to start with the $b_m$ because we have to consider that the two polynomials have different length - otherwise it would be a loss of generality.